# (JavaScript) Return the content of an array with an XML-like format

Tags: javascript, arrays, xml, return

I have an array with content similar to this:

`const array = [["name", "age", "city", "email"],["Peter", "30", "Madrid", "a@mail.com"],["Josh", "23", "NY", "b@mail.com"] ]`

And I have to return the content in this format:

```
<data>
 <name>Peter</name>
 <age>30</age>
 <city>Madrid</city>
 <email>a@mail.com</email>
 <name>Josh</name>
 <age>23</age>
 <city>NY</city>
 <email>b@mail.com</email>
</data>
```

I've tried every idea that has come to mind with no luck, so any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `for` loops, one to iterate arrays, another to iterate values.

```js
const array = [
  ["name", "age", "city", "email"],
  ["Peter", "30", "Madrid", "a@mail.com"],
  ["Josh", "23", "NY", "b@mail.com"]
]

const labels = array.shift()

let output = '<data>'

for (const item of array) {
  for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    output += `<${labels[i]}>${item[i]}</${labels[i]}>`
  }
}

output += '</data>'

document.getElementById('txt').value = output
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="txt"></textarea>
```